# How to create new rows from multiple data rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assume we have dataset. 
I want to create new dataset

here is the code:

```
cols=a.columns.tolist()
cols_new=[str(i) for i in cols]
col_rename_dict = {i:j for i,j in zip(cols,cols_new)}
A.rename(columns=col_rename_dict, inplace=True)
```

Comment: What do you expect us to do with your broken code? Please show us your data. Post it as text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

All this code:

```
cols=a.columns.tolist()
cols_new=[str(i) for i in cols]
col_rename_dict = {i:j for i,j in zip(cols,cols_new)}
A.rename(columns=col_rename_dict, inplace=True)
```

can be replaced by:

```
A.columns = A.columns.astype(str)
```

The whole thing can be replaced by:

```
pd.Series(A.columns).astype(str) + ':' + B.astype(str) + ':' + A.astype(str)
```

Putting it all together:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10).astype('uint8'))
new = pd.Series(A.columns).astype(str) + ':' + B.astype(str) + ':' + A.astype(str)
```

Which gives you `new`:

```
                       0                       1                     2 ...
0     0:0:0.271828540533    1:255:0.380711984606  2:0:-0.0485613686695   
1       0:0:1.0257878258     1:0:-0.496507979207   2:0:-0.619377627238
...
```

Comment: I think this is what OP wants, I used `B.apply(lambda x : str(x.name)+':'+x.astype(str)) +':'+ A.astype(str)` , but ur solution is actually good

Comment: @Bharath: You should never use `apply()` unless you are totally stuck and unable to proceed without it.  It should not be the default approach, because it is dead slow.

Comment: Now you know why I havent put that as an answer. :)

Comment: Voila ! This is exactly what I want